# The proof of differentiating the Riemann integral

Tags: integration

Does anyone know how to prove this: Suppose $f(x,t)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t)$ are continuous functions on $M=\langle a,b\rangle \times \langle c,d \rangle$. Then $I$ is differentiable on $\langle c,d \rangle $ and $ (\forall t \in \langle c,d \rangle) \frac{d}{dt}I(t)=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $t,h$ are such that $t,t+h \in [c,d]$. Then 
$f(x,t+h)-f(x,t) -{\partial f(x,t) \over \partial t}h = \int_t^{t+h} ({\partial f(x,s) \over \partial t} - {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial t})ds$. Since
the partial is continuous on the square $[a,b]\times [c,d]$, it is uniformly
continuous and so for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such
that if $|h| < \delta$, then
$|f(x,t+h)-f(x,t) -{\partial f(x,t) \over \partial t}h| \le \epsilon |h|$
for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Then $|I(t+h)-I(t) - \int_a^b {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial t} dx h| \le (b-a) \epsilon |h|$, from which it follows that
$I'(t) = \int_a^b {\partial f(x,t) \over \partial t} dx$.